# Shiny data table removing column header and sorting altogether

Tags: r, datatable, shiny, dt

I am trying to use a shiny data table without the header at all. I got to the point of not displaying column names, but can't seem to get rid of the header with sorting arrows:

```
library(DT)
df < data.frame(x = c('a', 'b', 'c'), y = c(1, 2, 3))
datatable(df, rownames = NULL, colnames = NULL, options = list(dom = 't'))
```

Is there any way to just get rid of the header totally?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know about the whole header, but this removes the sort ticks.

```
   library(DT)
    df <- data.frame(z = c('a', 'b', 'c'), y = c(1, 2, 3))
    datatable(df, rownames = NULL, colnames = NULL, options = list(dom = 't',bSort=FALSE))
```

Comment: Same here, any idea @IndranilGayen

Comment: @pommedeterresautee try this datatable(df, rownames = NULL, colnames = NULL, options = list(dom = 'b', ordering = F))

Answer (score 6):

`colnames = NULL` is not working now, it gives "no record found" message instead of data table. But empty strings works.
I used `colnames = c("", "", "", "", "")` for table with 5 columns to remove column names.
With help @Wilmar van Ommeren

```
library(DT)
df <- data.frame(x = c('a', 'b', 'c'), y = c(1, 2, 3))
datatable(df, rownames = NULL, colnames = '', options = list(dom = 't', bSort=FALSE))
```

Comment: `colnames = ""` was enough for me. Even with multiple columns